# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2 \pi k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form of this series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{2 \pi k}} $$
It can help to solve a very hard integral problem 
$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x \sin(x)\coth(x^2) .dx$

Comment: What is that hard integral? Don't keep it for yourself please :D

Comment: No closed form as per [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(e%5E(-sqrt(k)))+from+k%3D1+to+inf). How did that sum arise ? What's the integral ?

Comment: Check it now it's edited

Comment: Sorry. Unsolvable........